# Do I have to notify my ListAdapter when using MutableLiveData?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged, mutablelivedata

I'm new at Android ViewModel and I want to figure out whether I have to notify adapter when using MutableLiveData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't. The data updates on the `RecyclerView` whenever the `MutableLiveData`'s value changes